# Create calculated column to add dynamic values based on modified date

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have 2 columns in my SharePoint online list; total efforts and progressive efforts. Total efforts is a calculated column that captures values from progressive efforts column where the technical team enters the efforts for processing a request on a particular day. If a request is processed beyond a day, value entered in the progressive efforts column must be added to total efforts column based on the modified date, previously added value must not be replaced if modified date is same as handling completed date. How do i create a calculated column for adding dynamic values entered in progressive efforts column?

Regards,
Thushara

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow to do the calculation.

Then create an Information Management Policy-retention policy on the list to trigger the workflow when "Created + 1 day".

More information about triggering a workflow via Information Management policy, you can refer to:
[How to trigger a workflow on a timer basis: Information management policies](https://wardpeter.com/how-to-trigger-a-workflow-on-a-timer-basis-information-management-policies/)

Comment: I need to retain value entered in progressive efforts column in another column so i could add progressive efforts to it when ever the task is modified. My total efforts must be incremented automatically. For example, I spent 100 minutes on a task today and it must reflect 100 in total efforts. I work on the task after 2 days and spend 200 minutes, if I enter 200 minutes in progressive efforts column, my total efforts must show 300 minutes. How can I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go with MS flow as it is SharePoint online, do not create calculated columns. Create a normal number/single line of text column.

- Create a flow - add trigger point as created or modified.
- Do your calculation in flow using flow actions like - if, concat, addition
  etc..you would be able to do all sort of operations.
- Assign final  value and update the list item using update list item action.

Logic to be used for calculating total efforts columns.

- Create a variable CurrentEffort, assign it from progressive efforts
  column value
- Create a variable TotalEffort, assign it from Total efort column
  value
- Create a variable TotalNewEffort, assign it to Total efort column
  value
- Use incremental variable action, select total new effort as name of
  variable and add Value as CurrentEffort

So now you have to use update item, set TotalEfforts columns of list item to TotalNewEffort variable.

Comment: Hi again,thank you for the suggestion. would you please help me with the formula in MS flow.